# ScatterView item orientation and PrimarySurfaceDevice.Tilt

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense, scatterview

I'm working in Visual C# 2010 Express with WPF to develop an application for a Microsoft Surface table, and cannot for the life of me find the simple solution to this problem.

When using a ScatterView control without setting a custom template for scatterview items, the control throws new ScatterViewItems onto the screen at random orientations and positions. This, I like.

I am developing my program on a vertical screen, on which scatterViewItems are randomly thrown, except they are mostly upright, and never thrown on updide-down. What I am getting at is the control knows the screen is vertical and keeps the items from starting out upside down.

However, when I transfer the program to a device with a horizontal screen, the items are now thrown out randomly and OFTEN upside down from the original app orientation. Again **the ScatterView control is reading InteractiveSurface.PrimarySurfaceDevice.Tilt (or something like it) and compensating.**

**How do I make it stop doing this?**

I just want my items to continue to appear in the ScatterView as if the screen was vertical. Can I trick ScatterView into thinking it's vertical still? Can I turn this feature off? I would like to avoid making my own template for ScatterViewItems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if nobody can explain how ScatterView knows the screen tilt angle, and how to change that, then the only solution is to generate your own randomness. For reference, here's what I used to do this:

```
    ScatterViewItem item = new ScatterViewItem();
    item.Content = image;
    Random rand = new Random();

    item.Orientation = RandOrientation(-20, 20);
    item.Center = RandCenter(50);
    SSScatter.Items.Add(item);

    private Point RandCenter(int pad)
    {   
        int randx = rand.Next(pad, (int)SSScatter.Width-pad);
        int randy = rand.Next(pad, (int)SSScatter.Height-pad);
        return new Point(randx, randy);
    }

    private int RandOrientation(int low, int up)
    {
        int randor = rand.Next(low, up);
        return randor;
    }
```

I still wish there was a way to trick ScatterView...

Answer (score 0):

Set the Orientation property to 0 for each item.  The randomness only happens when you haven't explicitly set a value

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to keep the random orientations (or pseudo-random, since they still mostly stay upright on a vertical screen). I suppose I could make my own random orientation generator, but there's surely a better way to do this.

Comment: You'd have to do your own randomness... +/- 15 degrees would be good